# Mobile App webframe Authentication with Rails Devise

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am currently working on implementing a mobile app for our site that uses Ruby on Rails and Devise. The idea here is, at first, create a mobile login form that on successful login opens a web frame that is authenticated and allows the normal use of the (mobile optimised) site. Theoretically that should be possible.
I am having trouble with the following issues:

1. How do you get the pure session key for the user session via a json request? What methods can be used to manually generate it from devise, something that the `sign_in(:user, user)` method does?
2. Is it even possible to take that key and put it into the browser cookie the way it normally happens in devise, but on the mobile side?

I know that this is not the standard method of making mobile applications for the site, but I believe it should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so I decided to make a webframe solution as follows, basically you post the login and password to a certain sign_in method specially designed to generate one-time sign in tokens for the application. You need two methods in the system to do that:

routes.rb

```
devise_scope :user do
  get "sign_in_with_token/:token" => "sessions#sign_in_with_token"
  post "get_login_token" => "sessions#get_login_token"
end
```

sessions_controller.rb (don't forget to add the method that increases the failed_sign_in_count on wrong password, otherwise that can allow brute force attacks)

```
def get_login_token
  user = User.find_by_email(sign_in_params["login"])
  password = sign_in_params["password"]
  if user and user.valid_password?(password)
    token = SecureRandom.hex(16)
    user.update_attribute(:authentication_token, token)
    render json: {token: token}, status: 200
  else
    render json: {error: "error"}, status: 403
  end
end
```

and the method to sign in with that token

```
def sign_in_with_token
  @user = User.where(authentication_token: params[:token], email: Base64.decode64(params[:email])).first
  if @user
    @user.update_attribute(:authentication_token, nil)
    sign_in(@user, bypass: true)
  end
  redirect_to '/' # or user_root_url
end
```

That way the mobile app will work like this:

1. use the generic web frame to send ajax requests to the server and get that token for the user email if password is correct.
2. make a /sign_in_with_token/#{token from ajax}?email=#{base46 encoded email} link inside the app.
3. open that link inside the web frame and use the app as though you were logged in normally. Now the app can save email and password locally and use that logic to get the token again for another session. Later logging in will also be able to set the app id so that push notifications can be sent.

Appreciate any feedback or criticism on this solution.

Answer (score 6):

You might want to consider using [Devise Token Auth](https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth) and treating your mobile application like just another webapp that requests permission from your main site. DTA is particularly nice since it takes care of managing the session tokens (renewing/expiring) and passing them onto the app requiring access. The issue is overriding your session controllers so that it automatically logs in after you already log in on the mobile app (or just rewriting your log in so it occurs in conjunction with the Rails site, rather than before). Considering you're already using Devise, this may also be more refactoring than you'd like.

Comment: The idea is having the mobile application open a webframe, that acts like a normal site, but within the app. So the whole point of this approach is having a mechanism that does not need rewriting the entire logic of the server, just a way to manually pass on the session cookie to the webframe, the same thing that happens on normal browsers with normal logins.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to put your authentication form on the mobile UI and pass the credentials over to the web frame, you need a way to pass data from the mobile app to the web frame.

How you accomplish this depends on what platform you're building on. I'm not really a mobile developer so I don't know for certain how difficult / easy these options are:

1. When opening the web frame, instantiate it with session data
2. Find a way to call methods on the client from the web frame. Something like `getSessionData`.
3. You could generate a fingerprint for the web frame, have the mobile UI send this data to the server, and then have the web frame authenticate with the server by sending the fingerprint.

Again, I'm not entirely sure how possible all these options are.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly the problem. 1. how do you get the session key for a certain user in Rails and Devise. and 2. How do you pass this key over into the web frame.

Answer (score 2):

You should use token authorization and Android deep linking. It will allow you to login in the web browser and send a token to your app via deep linking.

Comment: I have an idea about how token authentication works, basically the system needs to be able to have a token in the head of the url as a parameter instead of a session key inside a browser cookie. But is there a way to get the session key manually inside rails and send it to the mobile app so that it could be set inside of its webframe?

Comment: You can deal this issue in such way: users signs in via a browser and sends to your app with deep linking and token. Using this token you can make authenticated requests.

Comment: If you need the session in a webview, user must login there.

Comment: So basically the app gets a "single use" sign in encrypted token on internal sign in (example /simple_sign_in?token=sdfsdfsdfsf), and clicking on that link (opening it in webview) will create a normal session anywhere I want?

Comment: You cannot create session manually. You can create it in webview only if user signs in there.

Comment: It is possible to manually trigger a session in devise with sign_in method. Authentication can be handled via a link with an encrypted token.